# Mapper files (*.xml) not exported on build project. Using mybatis

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, mybatis

I'm working on a maven project that use mybatis to DB tier. The `.xml` files isn't exported when I'm building the project. But the `.java` files are being exported and they are at the same package. So the project run is giving me an "not found" error.

I do a copy of `.xml` files and paste inside `target` folder (at the correct location) and the project runs perfectly.

my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


<modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion>

  
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.10</version>
  
  <name>Description</name>
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <!-- encoding: default é project.build.sourceEncoding -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!-- Para criação do JAR simples (sem dependências) -->
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.workload.exporter.DataExporter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <mainClass>com.workload.exporter.DataExporter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

There are any other config to set on my pom file?

Comment: Copying resources can be configured using `maven-resources-plugin`

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: It's worked. I just add the resources section like docs and the .xml files are exported correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have just added the resources section at my pom file, like @swapyonubuntu comment.

```
<resources>
  <resource>
     <directory>src/main/java</directory>
       <includes>
          <include>src/to/correct/folder/*.xml</include>
       </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```